# Looking for a task prompter kind of like Manna

Tags: android, web-apps, web-browser, productivity

The Manna software I refer to is from [Marshall Brain's essay](http://marshallbrain.com/manna1.htm) of the same name.

In the essay, the Manna software is a very sophisticated computer program that manages the operation of a fast-food restaurant by tasking the employees (likely) hundreds of times during a shift, telling them through an audio headset exactly what to do.

I'm interested in the basic mechanics of the software rather than employer-driven tasking of employees, or the creepy robots-are-taking-everything-over situation.

The essence I'm after is that the software has a collection of tasks (provided by me, the user), and then it gives them to me one at a time, sequentially, for as long as I want to do them.

My thinking is that this kind of thing may help me to get more done, because (a) it would keep things to some extent fresh, because I'd not know exactly what's coming next, and (b) I wouldn't need to think what to do next, because it would tell me.

A phone app, web app, or browser extension would be great (I'm an Android guy) but I'm willing to try other types of software. Some options as I go along like "do more of this kind of task" or "change it up" or "give me another task to do" would be great, and learning my preferences so that I get the most done would be the brass ring.